# How to document specialized C++ constructor with Doxygen?

Tags: c++, templates, doxygen

I have a class template that looks like that:

```
template< typename A >
struct MyClassTemplate
{
    /** \brief Foobar.
      */
    MyClassTemplate( A& );
};

template< typename A >
MyClassTemplate< A >::MyClassTemplate( A& )
{
}

template< >
MyClassTemplate< ClassB >::MyClassTemplate( ClassB& )
{
}
```

The page that Doxygen generates for `MyClassTemplate` lists two constructors, namely one taking `A&` as argument and one taking `ClassB&`. The problem is that it shows the second as undocumented. It also produces a warning that I want to get rid of:

> MyClassTemplate.h: warning: Member MyClassTemplate(ClassB &) (function) of class MyClassTemplate is not documented.

Based on that warning, I have already tried things like that and similar:

```
/** \fn MyClassTemplate::MyClassTemplate(ClassB&)
  * \brief
  * I am NOT undocumented!!!
  */
template< >
MyClassTemplate< ClassB >::MyClassTemplate( ClassB& )
{
}
```

But the warning remains and the page for `MyClassTemplate` still shows an undocumented constructor. How to document this s.t. Doxygen understands it?